# Printing all dictionary results from For Loop in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to print the results from all 3 names that are input, in a dictionary format.  Current code below only prints out the last name.  The 2 lines commented out (#) are what I was trying to change around to get it to work, clearly not doing it correctly.

```
def name():
    count = 0
    while (count  < 5):
        d = {}
        qs = dict(Fname='first name', Lname='last name')
        for k,v in qs.items():
            d[k] = input('Please enter your {}: '.format(v))
                #d['first name'].append(v)
                #d['last name'].append(v)
                count += 1
    print(d)

name()
```

Comment: `d` is not a list. It is a single dictionary. Each iteration through your `while` loop you create a *new* dictionary and assign it to `d`, so yes, after the last iteration, only the last such dictionary is still there.

Comment: @Alexander: don't just edit indentation like that. That's the very reason there is an issue here, you can't just go and fix indentation to what you think should be there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not sure what just happened but thanks.  Your first comment makes sense, I just need to figure out how to change that so the dictionary can be appended to and not overwritten

Comment: You don't append to the dictionary. Dictionary keys are unique. You want a **list** of dictionaries, so create a list before the `while` loop, and append your new dictionaries to that list.

Comment: You do want to clean up your counting. You count from `0` to `5`, but talk about asking for 3 names. You would normally increment your counter in the `while` loop, not in the nested `for` loop. Better still, don't use `while` and manual counting, just use a `for count in range(3):` loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks.  I'll clean it up and see if I can get it figured out

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry about that.  I didn't believe the indentation was the issue, hence why I tried to fix it.  I sometimes find the code that is pasted in SO isn't actually the OP's true code, rather it is their attempt to share it.

Comment: @Alexander sure, but with Python you always need to be careful you don’t then mask the actual problem. If you need to make changes to indentation to this extend, just don’t touch it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things that I'd change:

- append each record (`dictionary`) to a `list` of entries.
- (optional) Use a `for-loop` rather than a `while` as less lines of code.
- return the `entries` list, rather than `print` it as it is a `function` so I like to have outputs.

So here's the corrected code:

```
def name():
    entries = []
    for count in range(5):
        d = {}
        qs = dict(Fname='first name', Lname='last name')
        for k, v in qs.items():
            d[k] = input('Please enter your {}: '.format(v))
        entries.append(d)
    return entries

print(name())
```

---

For testing purpose, I modified it to just except `2` entries, but we can still see that it works:

```
Please enter your last name: fish
Please enter your first name: bowl
Please enter your last name: cat
Please enter your first name: mat
[{'Lname': 'fish', 'Fname': 'bowl'}, {'Lname': 'cat', 'Fname': 'mat'}]
```

Comment: As with the code posted by the OP, the `count` variable is a bit redundant. You can replace it with `_`. (Single underscore).

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  Most importantly, it makes sense reading it.  Thanks everyone

Comment: @quamrana Good point, but there is the possibility that they may want to use it.

Comment: Also, the `5` could be passed in as a parameter. Anyway top marks for an answer which does *not* perform a print within the function, but instead returns a result and you print the result of the call!

Answer (score 2):

Hope! you got it right from Martijin Comments, For reference to other adding this code:

```
def name():
    count = 0
    listOfDict = [] #creating empty list
    for count in range(3):
        dict = {}
        qs = dict(Fname = 'first name', Lname = 'last name' )
        for k,v in qs.items():
            d[k] = input('please enter your {}: '.format(v))
        listOfDict.append(d) # adding each item to the list.
        count += 1
    print listOfDict

name()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def name():
    count = 0
    while (count  < 5):
        d = {}
        qs = dict(Fname='first name', Lname='last name')
        for k,v in qs.items():
            a = input('Please enter your {}: '.format(v))
            d[v] = a
        count += 1
        print(d['first name'],d['last name'])

name()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict` to automatically create lists to store each entered value.  The main idea is that you want to append each entered value to a collection of some type (e.g. list).

```
from collections import defaultdict

number_of_entries = 3
dd = defaultdict(list)
for _ in range(number_of_entries):
    for key in ('first name', 'last_name'):
        dd[key].append(input('please enter you {}: '.format(key)))

>>> print(dict(dd))
{'first name': ['Adam', 'Milton', 'Irving'],
 'last_name': ['Smith', 'Friedman', 'Fisher']}
```